# ERROR in Javascript - Opening a URL PLUS the text input by the user using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

What's wrong with my javascript codes?

It's supposed to be an input box and a submit button. What ever the user will type in the input box will be added to the default web url, but it's not working.

Actually the error I encounter is that nothing is happening after I click the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn").click( function() {
    var url = "http://www.hellothere.com/print/" + $("#text").val();
    window.open(url);
});
 </script>


</head>

<body>
 <p>
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gv5bq/3/)

BTW, everything is working when i put those codes in JSFiddle. The problem starts when I transfer those same exact codes in Dreamweaver. Nothing is happening.

Comment: It's working in my machine, are you getting any error on console? make sure you have jquery included properly.

Comment: you have to add jquery file if added then check path is correct

Comment: yes. i have updated the jquery source. it's still not working. any ideas?

Comment: @KareenLagasca : Check your javascript console to see the errors...

Comment: Use a server like WAMPServer so you access your page through http://localhost/path/file.html instead of Dreamweaver (or at least by drag and drop of file into a browser, then the URL should be file:///C:/Users/etc but not sure it even works). Is it better then?

Comment: Ir's working in jsFiddle as the document.ready is already defined there but not in your code. Please check my full answer, I think it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as follows :

```
window.location = url;
```

This will redirect you to the `url`.

## Update :

The problem in your code is that you are defining the click function in the `head` before `btn` is defined. See the updated code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn").click(function() {
    var url = "http://www.hellothere.com/print/"; + $("#text").val();
    window.open(url);
});
</script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this I have defined the click function after `btn` is created. I have tested the code and it works perfectly.

Comment: yes the jsfiddle is really working. but when I put those codes in Dreamweaver. there goes the problem. nothing is happening.

Comment: Yep yep yep! hoooray! thanks for your code @parag. I will reward you now the 50 points!

Comment: Alternatively, wrap in $(document).ready(). It's possible that the difference in jQuery source may have also been causing a problem. This code loads it via http. The original code uses the protocol used when the page is loaded - which, in Dreamweaver, may have been file://.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   

    $('#btn').click(function (){

    var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/print/" + $('#text').val();
    window.location.href = url;

    });

  })
```

Comment: still no luck. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try your click function inside ready function like, $(document).ready(function() {   //Your click function here })

Comment: still not working. I wonder what's really wrong with the code.

Comment: here's the fiddle, the weird thing is it's working in jsfiddle but when i copy and paste this in dreamweaver, there goes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Gv5bq/

Comment: You should have to remove double quotes in $("#text").val() as $('#text').val()

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- You should not have a `<script>` element with **both** a `src` attribute and inline code. Split it into two separate elements.
- The inline code to reference the `#btn` element doesn't work, because the element doesn't exist yet at this point in the markup. Move it after the `#btn` element, or use a `$(document).ready()` or similar to delay the execution.
- Also, you should strive to produce [**valid HTML**](http://validator.w3.org/). Structurally unsound HTML may cause surprising DOM trees and other unexpected behaviour.

Perhaps *something* like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>    
 <title>JQuery click test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <p>
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btn").click( function() {
     var url = "?" + $("#text").val();
     window.location = url;
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver *possibly* accesses HTML files by the file:// protocol. Try changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I'd wrap your script up in a $(document).ready(function(){...});,  as suggested by Nisse Engstrom.

Answer (score 1):

You've to register the click event when the document is ready.

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('ready');

            $("#btn").click( function() {
                console.log('click')
                var url = "http://www.hellothere.com/print/" + $("#text").val();
                console.log(url);
                window.open(url);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="text">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">
    </p>
</body>
```

This thing will surely work, no issue at all. But http://www.hellothere.com/print/ website has a certain server code so that if it finds any url which is not valid then it redirects it to http://www.hellothere.com/print/ again so http://www.hellothere.com/print/test becomes http://www.hellothere.com/print/. That is not a bug of the code. Change the url to [ERROR in Javascript - Opening a URL PLUS the text input by the user using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583656/error-in-javascript-opening-a-url-plus-the-text-input-by-the-user-using-javasc/24726717#24726717) and you'll see the code'll work.

Comment: Hi Indra, sorry about the confusion. just replace the website hellothere.com to a fictitious website you prefer. as long as the goal is to open the assigned website + the text input of the user.

Comment: That's why I told you to change the url from http://www.hellothere.com/print/ to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583656/error-in-javascript-opening-a-url-plus-the-text-input-by-the-user-using-javasc/24726717#24726717 and use my code. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change your jQuery `src` from `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"` to `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"`.

Secondly, your js containing `"#btn"` is executed before you have defined `btn`. Move your script after you define `"#btn"`.